# Modifying Wide Pandas Data frame based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to edit values for a wide form of time series data based on a condition in python using the pandas library. The data is satellite observational values on a given date (see photo below). The first column is a unique id and all subsequent columns are date values. This means that each row is a time series for that specific id.

The idea is this:

if **n1** is the current observation and **n2** is the next observation and **n3** is the observation after that then:

```py
if ((n2 - n1) > 0.3) and (n3 >= (0.9 * n1)):
    n2 = (n1 + n3) / 2
```

Just to be clear, n1, n2, n3 are the first three values of this data frame, not attributes. For the attached example n1 would be 0.25916876 and n2 would be 0.25916876 and n3 would be 0.23824187.

How can I modify my Data frame with this rule? Could this be done with list comprehension?

[This is what df looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKDKf.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].  That means no images of code!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is named `df`, then you can try:

```py
mask = (df.n1 - df.n2 > 0.3) & (df.n3 >= (0.9*df.n1))
df.n2.where(~mask, (df.n1 + df.n3) / 2)
```

Comment: I should have specified more clearly that n1, n2, and n3 were just used to illustrate the rule. They are not attributes of the df. They would be the values of the first three indices of the row (excluding the id attribute of course).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this process for each column of the dataframe.
This is working with a fake dataframe I created to replicate the process:

```
# Iterate over each column
for c in list(df):
    df[c] = np.where((df[c]-df[c].shift(1, fill_value=0)>0.3) &
                     (df[c].shift(-1, fill_value=0) > 0.9*df[c].shift(1, fill_value=0)), 
                     np.mean(df[c].shift(-1, fill_value=0),df[c].shift(1, fill_value=0)), 
                     df[c])
```